# Issues installing MobileFirst Studio v7.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Trying to install MobileFirst Studio v7.1.0 into clean Eclipse install -- either Mars (v5.1) or Luna (v4.4.2). Receiving error when trying to confirm the features indicating missing requirements. Any thoughts or reasons for this?

[image: Eclipse error - missing pre-reqs]

Answer (score 1):

This has been identified as a defect introduced in a recent iFix and is in the process of being fixed. I will update this answer once a fixed version will be available via Eclipse Marketplace.

As a workaround you can install an [older release](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/mobilefirst_studio_plugin_7.1.0.zip) and then select to *update* it using the "faulty" release through Eclipse Marketplace. The update will work as the problem manifests itself only in *new* installations.

For reference, this is APAR - PI54604 CANNOT INSTALL MOBILEFIRST PLATFORM STUDIO 7.1 ON ECLIPSE.