# Can't install MobileFirst 7.1.0 studio on Eclipse Luna 4.4.2

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, eclipse-luna

I'm trying to install [Mobile First 7.1.0 platform studio](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/wl_welcome.html) on  Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2) - 64bit as written in Mobile First [requirements](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-mobilefirst-platform-studio). My java is as following:

```
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

I'm trying to install from Eclipse Marketplace and after few minutes of installation I get the following error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: IBM jQuery Mobile Tools 7.1.0.00-20151219-1535 (com.ibm.webtools.jquery.tools.licensed.feature.feature.group 7.1.0.00-20151219-1535)
  Missing requirement: IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.1.0.00-20151219-1535 (com.worklight.studio.feature.feature.group 7.1.0.00-20151219-1535) requires 'org.apache.commons.collections4 [4.0.0]' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.1.0.00-20151219-1535 (com.ibm.imp.tools.wce.feature.feature.group 7.1.0.00-20151219-1535)
    To: com.worklight.studio.feature.feature.group 7.1.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: IBM jQuery Mobile Tools 7.1.0.00-20151219-1535 (com.ibm.webtools.jquery.tools.licensed.feature.feature.group 7.1.0.00-20151219-1535)
    To: com.ibm.imp.tools.wce.feature.feature.group 7.1.0
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: [Issues installing MobileFirst Studio v7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34428545/issues-installing-mobilefirst-studio-v7-1/34437369#34437369)

This has been identified as a defect introduced in a recent iFix and is in the process of being fixed. I will update this answer once a fixed version will be available via Eclipse Marketplace.

As a workaround you can install an [older release](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/mobilefirst_studio_plugin_7.1.0.zip) and then select to *update* it using the "faulty" release through Eclipse Marketplace. The update will work as the problem manifests itself only in *new* installations.

For reference, this is APAR - PI54604 CANNOT INSTALL MOBILEFIRST PLATFORM STUDIO 7.1 ON ECLIPSE.

Comment: I think you meant this link http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/mobilefirst_studio_plugin_7.0.0.zip (7.0.0 instead of 7.1.0), at least it works :)

Comment: No, it should work with that linked 7.1 build as well.

Comment: It doesn't work, I've downloaded it and it gave me the same error, with 7.0.0 it works like you've described.

Answer (score 0):

@Idan: I have tried same steps as mentioned above but got the same error like @Anatoly. Let me know any other solution for the same.

Comment: He won't see your question, you should leave it as a comment to him answer.

Comment: I would assume the solution should be following Anatoly's steps (installed 7.0 then update from Marketplace until fixed).